# Not sure why my programm doesnt see if x>=

Tags: java

I just started learning java and i know my code is ugly so dont mind the ugliness.
So for school i have to write a programm in java that Checks what color is in your entered cordinates. I got assigned this picture http://prntscr.com/kt8jyh

I wrote some code but whenever i write coordinates like 2;2 then it outputs red, how do i solve this. 
And im not sure how this works, but i need the programm to output "white" whenever theres coordinates that are not colored. Whenever i try
else 
    System.out.println("white") 
it doesnt work i get error saying "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Syntax error on token "else", delete this token"

```java
Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Ievadi x");
String x1 = a.nextLine(); 

System.out.println("ievadi y"); 
String y1 = b.nextLine();   

float x = Float.parseFloat(x1);
float y = Float.parseFloat(y1);

if (x>=6 && x<=8 || y>=2 && y<=4)
    System.out.println("Red");
else if (x>=3-x && x<=x-11 || y<=4 && y>=9) {
    System.out.println("blue");
}
else if ((x-7) + (x-7) + (y-9) + (y-9) == 25) {
    System.out.println("Green") ;

    System.out.println("white");

}
```

Comment: Reasonable, consistent indentation would help.

Comment: `x <= x - 11` ... What specifically is the logic here?

Answer (score 0):

In this code

```
    else if ((x-7) + (x-7) + (y-9) + (y-9) == 25) {
              System.out.println("Green") ;
    // you can't put else here because it is inside a { } block              
                  System.out.println("white");
              }
```

what you can do is either close the block and start a new one.

```
    else if ((x-7) + (x-7) + (y-9) + (y-9) == 25) {
              System.out.println("Green") ;
    } else {
                  System.out.println("white");
              }
```

or not use { } blocks

```
    else if ((x-7) + (x-7) + (y-9) + (y-9) == 25) 
              System.out.println("Green") ;
    else 
              System.out.println("white");
```

Comment: I don't even see an `else` there; I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't have to use brackets when you only have single statement and you can add else statement to the end like following

```
if( x >= 6 && x <= 8 && y >= 2 && y <= 4 )
  System.out.print("Red");
else if( (x >= 2 && x <= 12 && y >= 4 && y <= 9 )  && ( (x <= 7 && y >= x ) || ( x > 7 && y <=x ) ) )
    System.out.print("Blue");
else if ( ( y >= 9 && y <=14 && x >= 2 && x <= 12 ) && ( y*y - (x-2)*(x-2) <= 5*5  ) )
    System.out.print("Green");
else
    System.out.print("White");
```

Comment: Nonetheless, I'd recommend doing it. Especially as a beginner. It is a common source for bugs that may be hard to find later on. In particular if the program is big and complex.

Comment: Java coding standards says that you should always use braces. It's a good idea to do always do so.  Clean and readable code isn't usually about minimizing the characters or line numbers, it's about being explicit and leaving little to interpretation so the code explains itself. https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html

Comment: @Zabuza I recommend developers use an IDE with code formatting from the start.